# How long will an ASP.NET MVC application run

Tags: asp.net-mvc, singleton, page-lifecycle

I wonder how long will an ASP.NET (MVC) application run, when no new requests come in? Lets say I'm using an IOC Container ans have a Singleton Object serving to the clients. As far as I know it will serve different page requests. But how long will it live when no new request come in? Is there any timeout (maybe configured through IIS) that says when my app will shut down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically it will run for 20 min because that is the default value for IIS7. You can configure that value, however.

Comment: That's basically 20 minutes (or whatever the configured value is) from the last request received.